# Drawing a Sphere and Calculating Surface Normals

Tags: opengl-es-2.0

I'm trying to draw a sphere and calculate its surface normals. I've been staring at this for hours, but I'm getting nowhere. Here is a screenshot of the mess that this draws:

[image]

```
- (id) init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {

        glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &_vertexArray);
        glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArray);

        glGenBuffers(1, &_vertexBuffer);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBuffer);

        GLfloat rad_th, rad_ph;
        GLint th, ph;
        GLint i = 0;

        GLKMatrix3 this_triangle;
        GLKVector3 column0, column1, column2, this_normal;

        for (ph=-90; ph<=90; ph++) {
            for (th=0; th<=360; th+=10) {

                if (i<3) printf("i: %d th: %f  ph: %f\n", i, (float)th, (float)ph);
                rad_th = GLKMathDegreesToRadians( (float) th );
                rad_ph = GLKMathDegreesToRadians( (float) ph);

                _vertices[i][0][0] = sinf(rad_th)*cosf(rad_ph);
                _vertices[i][0][1] = sinf(rad_ph);
                _vertices[i][0][2] = cos(rad_th)*cos(rad_ph);

                rad_th = GLKMathDegreesToRadians( (float) (th) );
                rad_ph = GLKMathDegreesToRadians( (float) (ph+1) );

                _vertices[i+1][0][0] = sinf(rad_th)*cosf(rad_ph);    
                _vertices[i+1][0][1] = sinf(rad_ph);     
                _vertices[i+1][0][2] = cos(rad_th)*cos(rad_ph);

                i+=2;
            }
        }

        // calclate and store the surface normal for every triangle
        i=2;
        for (ph=-90; ph<=90; ph++) {
            for (th=2; th<=360; th++) {
                // note that the first two vertices are irrelevant since it isn't until the third vertex that a triangle is defined.

                column0 = GLKVector3Make(_vertices[i-2][0][0], _vertices[i-2][0][1], _vertices[i-2][0][2]);
                column1 = GLKVector3Make(_vertices[i-1][0][0], _vertices[i-1][0][1], _vertices[i-1][0][2]);
                column2 = GLKVector3Make(_vertices[i-0][0][0], _vertices[i-0][0][1], _vertices[i-0][0][2]);
                this_triangle = GLKMatrix3MakeWithColumns(column0, column1, column2);
                this_normal = [self calculateTriangleSurfaceNormal : this_triangle];
                _vertices[i][1][0] = this_normal.x;
                _vertices[i][1][1] = this_normal.y;
                _vertices[i][1][2] = this_normal.z;                    

                i++;
            }
    i+=2;
        }

        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(_vertices), _vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
        glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(GLfloat)*6, NULL);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribNormal);
        glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribNormal, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(GLfloat)*6, (GLubyte*)(sizeof(GLfloat)*3));

        glBindVertexArrayOES(0);

    }

    return self;

}
```

- (void) render;
  {
  glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 65522);
  }

Here is my surface normal calculation. I've used this elsewhere, so I believe that it works, if given the correct vertices, of course.

```
- (GLKVector3) calculateTriangleSurfaceNormal : (GLKMatrix3) triangle_vertices
{
    GLKVector3 surfaceNormal;

    GLKVector3 col0 = GLKMatrix3GetColumn(triangle_vertices, 0);
    GLKVector3 col1 = GLKMatrix3GetColumn(triangle_vertices, 1);
    GLKVector3 col2 = GLKMatrix3GetColumn(triangle_vertices, 2);

    GLKVector3 vec1 = GLKVector3Subtract(col1, col0);
    GLKVector3 vec2 = GLKVector3Subtract(col2, col0);

    surfaceNormal.x = vec1.y * vec2.z - vec2.y * vec1.z;
    surfaceNormal.y = vec1.z * vec2.x - vec2.z * vec1.x;
    surfaceNormal.z = vec1.x * vec2.y - vec2.x * vec1.y;

    return GLKVector3Normalize(surfaceNormal);

}
```

In my .h file, I define the _vertices array like this (laugh if you will...):

```
// 360 + 2 = 362 vertices per triangle strip
// 90 strips per hemisphere (one hemisphere has 91)
// 2 hemispheres
// 362 * 90.5 * 2 = 65522
GLfloat _vertices[65522][2][3]; //2 sets (vertex, normal) and 3 vertices in each set
```

Comment: What on Earth is `_vertices` declared as? Generally you cannot pass a 3D array to OpenGL and expect it to do anything meaningful. I have to imagine there is some other data type that is making the 3D array subscript work on a linear block of memory, rather than doing a 3-level pointer indirection.

Comment: I edited my post to show how I am storing this crazy data structure. I'm really new at this, so I'm very receptive to better approaches. This method worked well for me with much smaller data sets, but it is unwieldy with this many vertices.

Comment: You know that the normals of a sphere are just its normalized vertices (and for a unit sphere as yours seems to be, they're just equal to the vertices), do you?

Comment: @Andon: In C (and thus also Objective-C as used in this question), declaring an array with multiple subscripts is pointer multiplication, not pointer indirection. The declaration `GLfloat _vertices[65522][2][3]` is effectively the same as `GLfloat _vertices[65522*2*3]`, and addressing an element as `_vertices[i][j][k]` is the same as `_vertices[i * 2*3 + j * 3 + k]`. See the [illustration on this page](http://rajkishor09.hubpages.com/hub/How-to-work-with-Multidimensional-Array-in-C-Programming). There's nothing wrong with this structure.

Comment: However, it can be useful to use `typedef`s to organize your vertex data semantically. If you define `typedef struct { GLKVector3 position; GLKVector3 normal; } Vertex`, you can declare your array as `Vertex _vertices[65522]` and address elements as `_vertices[i].position.x`, `_vertices[i].normal.z`, etc. It's still a long block of `GLfloats` as far as GL is concerned, but you can use names, `sizeof` and `offsetof` to keep track of things instead of having magic numbers all over your source code. (Sorry, not a solution to your problem but a general tip. @ChristianRau's comment should help.)

Comment: Thanks, everybody. @Christian Rau, no, I did not know that. If I just point my normals to the same vertices that I pointed my vertices, the sphere looks good. It draws with most of the upper hemisphere blacked out, but that must be another issue (maybe lighting). Thanks for that!

Comment: @Rickster: What, really? I could have sworn that x[1][2][3] meant to get the pointer at x[1]. After resolving this pointer, find the 3rd element to find the final pointer. And then return the 4th element from that array. That is how `float***` works. Anyway, the OP updated the question showing that the array has static dimensions, I was assuming it was a `float***` to facilitate dynamic size.

Comment: @Andon: C is flexible. If you have a `float***` variable, `x[1][2][3]` will perform multiple dereferences; if you have a `float[i][j][k]` array you've got a single block of memory and it'll do pointer arithmetic to resolve the subscripts.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are calculating normals for the triangles in your triangle strip, but assigning these normals to the vertexes which are shared by multiple triangles.  If you just used triangles instead of the triangle strip, and gave all three vertexes from each triangle that triangles normal, each triangle would have an appropriate normal.  This value would really only be correct for the center of the triangle.   You would be better off using vertex normals, which as Christian mentioned are equal to the vertexes in this case.  These could be interpolated across the triangles.